# Video hosting alternative to YouTube that isn't banned by corporates?

Tags: video, streaming, youtube

TLDR: Searching for a YouTube alternative that won't be blocked by corporates and allows private videos with "anyone with the link can view"

I'm trying to add a video presentation to my resume/cover letter while applying for jobs.

I want to make sure that hiring managers can view this video from their corporate machines. Sites like YouTube and Vimeo might be blocked, so I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to go about it. I thought about GitHub, but they don't let you stream the video online if it's larger than a given size, and the viewer will have to download the video.

I'd want the video to be private such that only people with the link are able to view it. This is an excellent feature in YouTube/GDrive/Dropbox but unfortunately all of them are probably blocked by corporates. Could anyone recommend a site that could help me solve this problem?

There is Odysee/LBRY but they won't allow deleting videos from the blockchain in the future if I want to. So not considering them for now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to upload it to a [Peertube instance](https://joinpeertube.org). A list of instances is [here](https://joinpeertube.org/instances#instances-list).

Comment: Would it allow me to delete the video in the future if needed? Also, any chance instance(s) might get deleted because of which my videos might get lost?

Comment: Yes, if the instance goes down, your video is offline too. If YouTube would be closed, every video is offline there too. If it would allow you to delete the video? Yes, it allows you to. I don't know what you can change with a instance as a administrator, but I think they can't turn it off.